# fastest method to keep top 2 values of each row in a matrix (or data.frame) in R

Tags: r

Assume I have the matrix `M` and I just want to keep the 2 highest values of each row in these matrix and others will be set to zero.

```
M <- rbind(c(0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7), c(0.8, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4))

> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.1  0.6  0.2  0.3  0.7
[2,]  0.8  0.1  0.7  0.2  0.4
```

I want this result.

```
rbind(c(0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.7), c(0.8, 0, 0.7, 0, 0))


>  rbind(c(0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.7), c(0.8, 0, 0.7, 0, 0))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.6  0.0    0  0.7
[2,]  0.8  0.0  0.7    0  0.0
```

I understand `apply(M, 1, sort)` can do this, but if the matrix `M` is large, it will be slow, so what is the fastest way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach with `pmax`:

```
m <- M
x1 <- do.call(pmax, lapply(1:ncol(M), function(x) M[, x]))
m[m == x1]  <- NA
x2 <- do.call(pmax, c(lapply(1:ncol(M), function(x) m[, x]), na.rm = T))
M[M != x1 & M != x2] <- 0
M
```

Some timings.  Setting up a large matrix, and then running a couple of the other proposed approaches:

```
set.seed(1234)
M <- matrix(floor(rnorm(1e7, 100, 10)), nc = 10)
f1 <- function(M) {
  m <- M
  x1 <- do.call(pmax, lapply(1:ncol(M), function(x) M[, x]))
  m[m == x1]  <- NA
  x2 <- do.call(pmax, c(lapply(1:ncol(M), function(x) m[, x]), na.rm = T))
  M[M != x1 & M != x2] <- 0
  M  
}

f2 <- function(M) {
  dt <- as.data.table(M)
  dt[, grp := 1:.N]
  dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "grp")
  dt_max <- dt[ dt[ order(-value), .I[c(1,2)], by = .(grp)]$V1 ]
  dt[, value := 0]
  dt[ dt_max, on = c("grp", "variable"), value := i.value]
  as.matrix(dcast(dt, formula = grp ~ variable))  
}

f3 <- function(M) {
  tmp <- data.frame(row=c(row(M)), val=c(M), seq=seq_along(M))
  tmp <- tmp[do.call(order,c(tmp[1:2],decreasing=TRUE)),]
  M[tmp$seq] <- with(tmp, ave(val,row,FUN=function(x) replace(x, -(1:2), 0) ))
  M
}
```

Benchmarking using `microbenchmark`, as proposed by @SymbolixAU:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1 = { f1(M) }, 
  f2 = { f2(M) }, 
  f3 = { f3(M) },
  times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#    f1   926.9069   946.6892  1084.038  1009.497  1082.454  1476.972    10 a  
#    f2  6315.3971  6750.1864  7327.610  7237.323  7785.078  9198.780    10  b 
#    f3 13076.0617 13435.9920 15360.451 15118.323 16497.295 19792.398    10   c
```

In addition, if there are duplicates of the largest two numbers for a given row, the other approaches seem to set the duplicates to zero.

Comment: the fastest one from Weihuang. Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, but how does this scale in execution time if I now want the top 7 values retained?

Comment: Also, `do.call(pmax, data.frame(M)))` might simplify the code with practically no difference in timings.

Comment: To SymbolixAU and thelatemail:  `matrixStats::rowMaxs` is good function to finish my question and the speed is faster than @Weihuang Wong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I propose using `data.table`, which involves a bit of reshaping, but should be quick. If you can get away without having to do the final reshape step at the end it should save some time too.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(M)

## define a 'grouping variable', which in this case is just the row number
## this lets us keep track of the row of the matrix
dt[, grp := .I]

## melt into long form
dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "grp")

## order the data by the value, for each group, and select the top 2 rows
dt_max <- dt[ dt[ order(-value), .I[c(1,2)], by = .(grp)]$V1 ]

## set all the original values to 0
dt[, value := 0]

## then overwrite those 0s with the 'top 2' values in dt_max
dt[ dt_max, on = c("grp", "variable"), value := i.value]

as.matrix(dcast(dt, formula = grp ~ variable))
     grp  V1  V2  V3 V4  V5
[1,]   1 0.0 0.6 0.0  0 0.7
[2,]   2 0.8 0.0 0.7  0 0.0
```

Comment: `dt[, grp := 1:.N]` can be simplified with `dt[, grp := .I]`

Comment: @BioChemoinformatics - mine isn't the quickest solution, however.

Comment: No problem. You are the first answer with comparable speed and relatively easy understand. @Weihuang Wong is the fastest one until now. I will learn that.

Comment: @SymbolixAU  By using the new benchmark, Weihuang's one is 7-fold faster than you. I must accept his answer this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some logic as @SymbolixAU, but using base R functions:

```
tmp <- data.frame(row=c(row(M)), val=c(M), seq=seq_along(M))
tmp <- tmp[do.call(order,c(tmp[1:2],decreasing=TRUE)),]
M[tmp$seq] <- with(tmp, ave(val,row,FUN=function(x) replace(x, -(1:2), 0) ))
M

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  0.0  0.6  0.0    0  0.7
#[2,]  0.8  0.0  0.7    0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mx1 = max(M[1,])
wh1 = which(M[1,]==mx,arr.ind=TRUE)
mx2 = max(M[1,-wh1])
wh2 = which(M[1,-wh1]==mx2,arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Then just assign these given values to these given indexes in some newly allocated zero array.

Comment: sry, meant this:  ==mx1    Also, can finish up by assigning 0 using this syntax: M[1,-c(wh1,wh2)] = 0   And then do for every row using lapply.

Comment: better to edit your answer, rather than as a comment

Comment: buildLocalMatrix <- function(fullMat, topK = 3) { # fullMat: full matrix
 library(matrixStats)
 fullMat2 <- fullMat
 for (i in 1:topK) {
   maxV <- matrixStats::rowMaxs(fullMat2, value = TRUE)
  fullMat2[fullMat2 == maxV] <- -1000
 }
 fullMat[fullMat < maxV] <- 0
 # return value
 return(fullMat)
}

Comment: @SymbolixAU I can not edit it with good format, but the `buildLocalMatrix()` is the function I used now, which is fast based on the idea of `pmax()`. Thanks.